# Encoding issue with XML

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm having an issue where the following HTML is stored in my database:

```
Carer £4.20 per person<br />
```

And is being output to XML with DOMDocument, as follows:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($page->content);
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;

//create the root element
$root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
$xmlDoc->createElement("document"));

$page->appendChild(
$xmlDoc->createElement("content", $content));
```

Resulting in

```
Carer &#xA3;4.20 per person&lt;br /&gt;
```

However, instead of the HEX encoding, is it possible to have the named HTML entities, e.g `&pound;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, instead of the HEX encoding, is it possible to have the named HTML entities, e.g `&pound;` ?

Yes and No. First of all no because you are using a XML and in XML there is no such named entity `&pound;` by default.

Yes, because you can output HTML instead ;) Let's see the example ([online-demo](http://eval.in/13168)):

```
$content = htmlspecialchars('Carer £4.20 per person<br />');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;


//create the root element
$root = $doc->appendChild(
    $doc->createElement("document")
);

$root->appendChild(
    $doc->createElement("content", $content)
);

echo "Save XML:\n", $doc->saveXML();
echo "\n\nSave HTML:\n", $doc->saveHTML();
```

And the output:

```
Save XML:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <content>Carer &#xA3;4.20 per person&lt;br /&gt;</content>
</document>


Save HTML:
<document><content>Carer &pound;4.20 per person&lt;br /&gt;</content></document>
```

So remember: In XML there is a very limited set of named entities, in HTML there are many more. You can also add more named entities to XML. If you'er interested, please see

- [Named Character Elements for XML](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/01/02/xmlchar.html) (by Anthony Coates, Zarella Rendon; 2 Jan 2003)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if your XML contains non ASCII characters, and the file was saved as single-byte ANSI (or ASCII) with no encoding specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the htmlspecialchars and see what happens?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Very easy - just use `htmlentities()` instead of `htmlspecialchars()`.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

*But be warned* - XML does **not** know HTML-entities like `&pound;`!
If you output XML, not HTML, then numeric references are the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it should be possible - but it depends.

Look at [pound](http://www.gocurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/one-pound-coin.jpg) from "[IT view](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/hfng/hfng1010/hfng101000005/8002249-british-pound-and-american-dollar-on-a-computer-keyboard-concept-exchange-rate-or-online-shopping.jpg)".

- `£` - sing of pound
- `pound` - name of currency
- `&pound;` - entity name
- `&#163;` - entity code

Now, let's write all items from above without marking it as `code`. What is result?

**£, pound, £, £** - as you see, 3rd and 4th has resulted to £ - but this is HTML. Belive me, [I don't lie](http://stepolabs.com/upload/pounds) :P

But I **strongly recommend** you to use `&#163;` in **XML**!

If you wantmore info, you can visit:

- [Using the British pound sign in an XML feed to be read by an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890495/using-the-british-pound-sign-in-an-xml-feed-to-be-read-by-an-iphone)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign